# Comparation of values in minimal submanifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $\phi: M^m\to H^n(k)$ be minimal immersion. Show that 
$$\varepsilon_1\leq\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\int_{\{r=s\}}|\nabla^{\top}r|d\lambda(s)}{\displaystyle\int_0^s\sinh^{m-1}\left(\sqrt{-k}t\right)dt}\leq\varepsilon_2,$$
where $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$, $H$ is hyperbolic space with curvature $k<0$ and $r$ is distance function in $H$.

Comment: Distance from what? Where does $M,$ or possibly $\phi,$ appear in this? Overall, what is the source of this, and why do you think that it is true, or might be true?

Comment: What is varying? It looks like that middle thing is a positive constant in which case the existence of such $\varepsilon$ is trivial.

Comment: The distance function is in hyperbolic space $H$ and $\nabla^{\bot}r(\phi(x))$ is distance function in immersed submanifold. The estimate desired is for all $s$.